# Install discord on raspberry pi

Tags: python, discord

I have been trying to install discord on my raspberry pi, but its saying error code 1 and I need a more updated version of python (3.4.5). However, Thonny Python says it's version is 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Python on raspberry pi comes preinstalled with version 2 and version 3 of python

Try using `pip3 install discord` and see if that fixes it